# Issues Installing GCC (C Compiler)

Tags: windows, gcc, mingw

GCC will not download for me. I know why but I don't know how to fix it. I've been trying to follow a few Youtube tutorials as well as this page: http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Getting_Started to download the MinGW GCC compiler so I can compile my C Code.

It seems like there's a new downloading interface that's different from the tutorial videos - I can post the vids if they'll help but each time I try to run GCC through the command prompt I'm getting the unrecognized command reply. Basically it seems I can not just pick the C Compiler and hope it'll work (like some of the videos say), it seems like I must pick each and every file individually from the GUI - which I actually have and still am unsuccessful. Some files were missing from the list, in particular some dll files but here's the list of files:

```
binutils (bin and dev)
mingw-runtime (dev and dll)
w32api
Required runtime libraries for GCC:
    mpc (dev and dll)
    mpfr (dev and dll)
    gmp (dev and dll)
    pthreads (dev and dll)
    iconv (dev and dll)
    zlib
    gettext
gcc-core (bin and dev and dll)
```

What I don't get is that I'm trying to run the automated installer and yet I still have to pick files.

Also I've already added it to the correct C directory to the PATH.

Comment: Did you read this [HOWTO](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/HOWTO_Install_the_MinGW_GCC_Compiler_Suite) already? I guess so, but just in case you didn't, it might help.

Comment: Yes I did, but I still have to pick individual files off a list to configure it correctly. I'm a little at a loss because there's a giant list of files to pick from, these files are specified as the list I've provided, but I wasn't expecting to pick files because theyre on the manual section. So am I wondering if I am instlaling it correctly? To make matters worse, the older tutorials seem to be targeting a different GUI.

Comment: If you mean the so called Installation Manager, I too have tried to find a way to simply select everything. There doesn't seem to be any. Heck, even clicking one of the checkbox like controls to select a package (and I agree, there are very many) is pretty annyoing, since you must press the menu item that pops up to actually select it. -- You can select the Basic setup to get started, I guess.

Comment: Yes but will the basic setup give me the ability to compile C programs?

Comment: I am still installing, so I don't know yet, but I assume so, since gcc (MinGW means "Minimal GCC for Windows", IIRC) is mainly a C and C++ compiler. All the rest is nice, but probably not crucial.

Comment: And if it doesn't, you can always add more stuff. <g>

Comment: From that list, the files I have been unable to load are:

mingw-runtime (dev and dll)
gmp (dll ONLY)
mpc (dll ONLY)
mpfr (dll ONLY)
pthreads(dll ONLY)